# Regex: Matching one substring, but excluding another substring later on

Tags: javascript, regex

Trying to write a regex that matches certain URLs. For our purposes, let's assume the URLs are:

```
http://website.com/Section/subsection/Cows
http://website.com/Section/Cows
http://website.com/Section/subsection/Chickens
```

I want to match:

- URLs that contain /Section/
- Unless it is followed by /Chickens

The closest I've gotten is `/\/Section\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/(?!Chickens)/gi`

This works for the first URL, but the 2nd URL will not be matched. I know it is because it doesn't have the `[a-zA-z0-9]+` section, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: `url.indexOf('/Section') != -1 && url.indexOf('/Chickens') != -1`

Comment: Do you need to make sure that its a valid URL? If so, you will need a much larger regex. I would use someone else's URL matcher code and then do what @adeneo suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were quite close. Here is the regex:

```
\/Section\/(?!.*\/Chickens)
```

It just matches the section part and then asserts that *anything followed by "/Chickens"* cannot match going forward.

You can tail the regex off with an additional `.*` (outside the negative lookahead) if you want it to capture the URL path instead of just testing for a match.

Answer (score 0):

You're close. Try this regex:

```
/\/Section\/([a-z0-9]+)(?!\/Chickens)/gi
```

Answer (score 0):

This one rejects "/Section/Chickens" as well :

```
var r = /\/Section\/(?!(.+\/)*Chickens(\/|\?|#|$))/;
r.test('/Section/Cows'); // true
r.test('/Section/Chickens'); // false
r.test('/Section/CowsChickens'); // true
r.test('/Section/ChickensCows'); // true
r.test('/Section/Cows/Chickens'); // false
r.test('/Section/Cows/Cows/Chickens'); // false
r.test('/Section/Cows/Chickens/Cows'); // false
```